# How to show a List of value vertically in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

`request.setAttribute("timeSheet_ID", timeSheet_ID);
            request.setAttribute("employee_id", employee_id);
            request.setAttribute("Assignment_ids", Assignment_ids);
            request.setAttribute("task_names", task_names);
            request.setAttribute("Dates", Dates);
            request.setAttribute("durations", durations);
            request.setAttribute("project_names", project_names);`

My servlet has a above code. Every request.setAttribute has a set of n number of values.

```
<td>${employee_id}</td>  
<td>${timeSheet_ID}</td> 
<td>${Assignment_ids}</td>
<td>${task_names}</td>
<td>${Dates}</td>
<td>${durations}</td>
<td>${project_names}</td>
```

In my jsp page am having a above code to display those values from request.setAttribute. It showing like a values as

### Employee ID Timesheet Id Assignment Id Task Name Dates Duration Id Project Name

```
[71, 71, 71, 71, 71] [56, 57, 58, 59, 60] [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [View Task, View Task, View    Task, View Task, View Task] [2013-09-30, 2013-10-01, 2013-10-02, 2013-10-03, 2013-10-04] [15, 12, 15, 15, 15] [Timesheet Application, Timesheet Application, Timesheet Application, Timesheet Application, Timesheet Application]
```

But i need to show the values as a Table format
eg.,

### Employee ID  Timesheet Id Assignment Id Task Name   Dates     Duration    Project Name

```
71            56             2          View Task 2013-09-30     2      Timesheet Appli
71            57             2          View Task 2013-09-30     3      Timesheet Appli
71            58             2          View Task 2013-09-30     5      Timesheet Appli
71            59             2          View Task 2013-09-30     5      Timesheet Appl
71            60             2          View Task 2013-09-30     4      Timesheet Appli
```

I just try with using "c:forEach" . but i does not showing as a vertically.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <table>
  <c:forEach ... >
  <c:set var="count" value="0"/>
  <tr>
      <td>${employee_id[count]}</td>  
      <td>${timeSheet_ID[count]}</td> 
      <td>${Assignment_ids[count]}</td>
      <td>${task_names[count]}</td>
      <td>${Dates[count]}</td>
      <td>${durations[count]}</td>
      <td>${project_names[count]}</td>
      <%=count++%>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
<table>
```